# Laravel 6.2: Laravel "with" not working with condition

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6.2

I'm working on a project in Laravel 6.2. I've two models.

1. Job
2. Company

What i want to do is to get all the jobs where the job title matches `something` and the `company city` is equal to `something`. The problem is, it's getting all the job with the companies but if i specify the wrong `company city`, it still gets the records. In short the condition inside the **`with`** not working. What i've done so far:

**Model > Job.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Job extends Model
{
    // user
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    // company
    public function company()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Company');
    }
}
```

**Model > Company.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Company extends Model
{
    // user
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    // job
    public function job()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Job');
    }
}
```

**JobController > search**

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
     $jobs = Job::where('title', 'like', '%' . $request->q . '%')
               ->with(['company' => function($q) use ($request) {
                    $q->where('city', $request->city);
                }])
                ->get();


     return view('jobs.view')->withJobs($jobs);
}
```

Comment: Hello, in your condition where after you have to ` ->get ();`

Answer (score 1):

Try the below funtion:

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
     $jobs = Job::where('title', 'like', '%' . $request->q . '%')
               ->with(['company'])
               ->whereHas('company',function($q) use ($request) {
                    $q->where('city', $request->city);
                })
                ->get();


     return view('jobs.view')->withJobs($jobs);
}
```

Comment: Your answer's code working even if i remove the `->with(['company'])` part. Why ?

Comment: `->with(['company'])` will just select the company relation,whereHas will filter on company's city. if you want company detail then you can use "with(['company'])",if you don't then you can remove that part.

Comment: company details are still available if i remove that part

Answer (score 0):

in your controller!

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
   $jobs = Job::where('title', 'like', '%' . $request->q . '%')
           ->with(['company' => function($q) use ($request) {
                $q->where('city', $request->city)->get();
            }])
            ->get();


   return view('jobs.view')->withJobs($jobs);
}
```